# PyQt5: self is NoneType when using slot/signals

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, attributeerror, signals-slots

I'm having some problems when trying to use slot/signals on a custom class.

The class looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QPixmap

class Screenshot(QtCore.QObject):
    newScreenshotTaken = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QPixmap)
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    captureInterval = 5 * 60

    def __init__(self):
        super(Screenshot, self).__init__()

    def startCapture(self):
        self.capture()

    def stopCapture(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def on_userStartedCapture(self):
        self.startCapture()

    def on_userStoppedCapture(self):
        self.stopCapture()

    def capture(self):
        print("capture!")
```

The error happens at on_userStartedCapture(self):

```
  File "/Volumes/HD2/test/screenshot.py", line 23, in on_userStartedCapture
    self.startCapture()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startCapture'
```

Emit is called from another class:

```
self.userStartedCapture.emit()
```

And the connect is done at main.py:

```
screenshot = Screenshot()
mainWindow = MainWindow()

mainWindow.userStartedCapture.connect(screenshot.on_userStartedCapture)
```

The strange thing is that self works on all slots/signals in my application. But I can't find out why this specific one is failing.

Any ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: The error is raised because `self` is `None` at the time the signal is sent. Which is to say, the instance of `Screenshot` the signal is connected to has been deleted (or is in the process of being deleted). Obviously it is difficult to be more precise than that, since you have omitted the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: @ekhumoro that makes sense. The Screenshot instantiation was done in the __init__ of class AppWindow which extends QtWidgets.QWidget. What is the proper way to keep it available during the entire execution of the application?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks! I just changed the screenshot instance to a class property instead of a local variable in __init__ and it worked. Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Glad to hear you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because `self` is `None` at the time the signal is sent. Which is to say, the instance of `Screenshot` the signal is connected to has been deleted (or is in the process of being deleted).